# Truncated body in tabular array mode

Tags: arrays

I have the following format :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[total={7in,10in},top=1in, left=0.6in,right=0.6in, includefoot]{geometry}.
\newpage

\newcommand{\matrix}[1]{\begin{array}{ccc}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\dbkt}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\newcommand{\bkt}[3]{\left#1 #2\right#3}
\newcommand{\eqnn}[2]{\begin{equation}#1\label{eq:#2}\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{array}{ll}
blaaah !!\\

&\begin{array}{l}
blaah !!
\end{array}

\end{array}
\end{document}\
```

I don't understand why the body doesn't get extended into the next page. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide us a good [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. code that is both compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, and minimal. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Apart from the problem you've mentioned, there are several errors in your code. Can you remove them so one can know exactly what you are referring to?

Comment: The environment `array` requires math mode.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX reports many errors when you run your example. In such a case it really isn't worth asking why the output looks any particular way: any output is essentially accidental.

If you fix the reported errors:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[total={7in,10in},top=1in, left=0.6in,right=0.6in, includefoot]{geometry}


%\newcommand{\matrix}[1]{\begin{array}{ccc}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\dbkt}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\newcommand{\bkt}[3]{\left#1 #2\right#3}
\newcommand{\eqnn}[2]{\begin{equation}#1\label{eq:#2}\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\cchapter}[1]{\chapter[#1]{\centering #1}}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{ll}
blaaah !!\\

&\begin{array}{l}
blaah !!
\end{array}

\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

you get

[image]